# Odoo model Creation

Tags: odoo

I create a module in Odoo12, but I encounter the following error:

> model not found

Can anyone help?

$model.py

```
from odoo import models, fields
    class StudentRecord(models.Model)
   _name = "my.student.name"
    name = fields.Char(string="name")
```

$view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <odoo>
   <data>
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_id">
    <field name="name">studentname</field>
    <field name="model">my.student.name</field>
    <field name="priority" eval="16"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
      <tree string="Idea list">
        <field name="name"/>
      </tree>
    </field>
    </record>
   </data>
  </odoo>
```

## error

```
 Model not found: my.student.name
```

Error context:
View `student name`

Comment: Please share the code of __init__.py file. I think you didn't add py file in __init__.py file.

Comment: Please post all imports in that file.

Answer (score 0):

Did you give the py file name in **init**.py file?
Try commenting the views path from manifest and run. Then uncomment and run to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

add your model to ir.model.access.csv like `access_my_student_name,access_my_student_name,model_my_student_name,,1,1,1,1`

1,1,1,1 - read, write, create, delete

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sure python indentations are correct and this model defined file name added to **init**.py

```
from odoo import models, fields
class StudentRecord(models.Model):
    _name = "my.student.name"
    name = fields.Char(string="name")
```

Answer (score 0):

3 possibilities here,

1. init.py file not set properly
   it should be like:
   from . import model
2. give access to your model from csv file, as said by @Artem Strogin
3. it should be something like this

from odoo import models, fields

class StudentRecord(models.Model)

```
_name = "my.student.name"

name = fields.Char(string="name")
```